# Set HEAD to the latest commit of tracked branch

Tags: git, branch

Suppose, I've been working on BranchA, which I created using this command:

```
git checkout -b BranchA -t origin/main
```

where `main` is a main development branch.

I was done working on this branch, pushed the changes, created a Pull Request to `main`.

Then I started working on a new feature which is dependent on changes I made in `BranchA` (that hasn't been merged into `main` yet). So, I created a new branch, using this command:

```
git checkout -b BranchB -t origin/BranchA
```

Same routine. Finished development, pushed the changes, created a pull request to merge into `main`.

While waiting for the approval on my PRs, I've noticed that there were some conflicts in the pull request for original `BranchA`. I did the merge, resolved conflicts, pushed back.

Now, since `BranchB` was created from `BranchA` I would expect it to automatically fetch the changes I made to `BranchA`, however `BranchB` HEAD is stuck a few commits below BranchA, i.e.:

[image]

I tried to do pull on `BranchB` to no avail.

**So, how do I move `HEAD` of `BranchB` on top of the latest commit I made for `BranchA`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BranchB execute "git rebase origin/BranchA"